# How do I create a range from a begin and end iterator?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have an object with functions for getting the begin and end iterators:

```
const_iterator err_begin() const
const_iterator err_end() const
```

Because they are not named `begin` and `end`, I cannot pass my object directly to functions in range-v3.

Is there a simple wrapper I can use to make this object work with the range-v3 library?

For example:

```
auto hasErrors = !empty(something(x.err_begin(), x.err_end()));
```

Comment: Add `begin()` and `end()` that call these two functions, respectively?

Comment: The object is part of a library. I cannot change the method names or add new methods.

Comment: Create the simple wrapper you are talking about that maps the begin and end calls to the ones you want.

Comment: Add overloads to `begin` and `end` functions for your object. They don't need to be methods

Comment: `class_name::const_iterator begin(class_name& obj) { return obj.err_begin(); }`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++20 onwards, you're looking for [`subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange):

```
auto hasErrors = !empty(std::ranges::subrange{x.err_begin(), x.err_end()});
```

---

If you're still using Ranges-v3, you'll want [`iterator_range`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1iterator__range.html):

```
auto hasErrors = !empty(ranges::make_iterator_range(x.err_begin(), x.err_end()));
```

Comment: The documentation for `iterator_range` lives [here](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1iterator__range.html). Just call `ranges::make_iterator_range(x.err_begin(), x.err_end())`.

Comment: I cannot find `iterator_range` and `make_iterator_range` from the code anymore. Have they been renamed?

Comment: @EricNiebler, why do we need `iterator_range`, while we can simply create a `range` of iterators?..

Comment: Ah, are you using the Microsoft fork of range-v3 for MSVC? In that (very out-of-date) fork, `iterator_range` was called `range`. It isn't any longer.

Comment: For future readers: in C++20 `std::ranges::subrange` seems to have replace `ranges:make_iterator_range`.

Answer (score 4):

You clarified that the class in question is part of a library that you cannot change. Fine. Create a facade class:

```
class FacadeClass {

      const RealClassWithErrBeginEnd &r;

public:

      FacadeClass(const RealClassWithErrBeginEnd &r) : r(r) {}

      auto begin() const { return r.err_begin(); }
      auto end() const { return r.err_end(); }
};
```

This should be good enough to fool most code that expects a container. In the worst case, you might need to provide additional typedefs in the facade, i.e. `value_type`, etc...

Comment: This type is not [Regular](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14000046/195873). It will not play nicely with the rest of the range-v3 library. Brian's answer below is the correct answer. (I'm the author of range-v3, FWIW.)

Answer (score 0):

`boost::make_iterator_range` will do the right thing. Now add a little ADL and we find that one free function solves all our problems:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/range.hpp>


// simulate the library class
struct X
{
    auto err_begin() const { return errors.begin(); }
    auto err_end() const { return errors.end(); }

    std::vector<std::string> errors;

};

// provide a generator to build an iterator range
auto errors(const X& x)
{
    return boost::make_iterator_range(x.err_begin(), x.err_end());
}

// do things with the iterator_range
int main()
{
    X x;
    for (const auto& err : errors(x))
    {
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << empty(errors(x)) << std::endl;
}
```