# How to wrap Callable to make it regular type?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17, regular-type

I'm writing an iterator facade, but it seems like my iterator will violate even basic [`Iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) concept. The problem is that the iterator accepts any [`Callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable), which might render fundamental operations on Regular Types ill formed. I'm following definition [presented](http://stepanovpapers.com/DeSt98.pdf) by Alexander Stepanov. Here is the declaration:

```
template<typename Callable, typename Iterator>
class transform_iterator
```

**Question:** How to wrap callable to make it regular type?

Actually I need wrapper only to be:

- Copy constructible
- Copy assignable
- Destructible

and not Regular Type in general.

**My first attempt**: wrap into [`std::optional<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
template <typename T>
class regular_box
{
    std::experimental::optional<T> value;
public:

//constructors, operator=

    template <typename ... ArgTypes>
    auto operator()(ArgTypes&& ... args)
    {
        return callable.value()(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
    }
};
```

But it doesn't solve the problem with assignment, since if `Callable` is not copy assignable, the `regular_box` will not be copy assignable as well.

**Plan B**: `std::function<>`. Though I would like to postpone it for as long as possible.

I could make multiple levels of fallbacks, but I couldn't find any better solution than that.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: @bolov, I store Callable as member of my transform iterator. So, if it is not regular, it will violate Iterator concept.

Comment: @Incomputable I'm not sure what you mean by "regular". Do you mean "copyable"?

Comment: @TartanLlama, added the link to the paper by Alexander Stepanov. There is a table, which is actually the vital part.

Comment: @TartanLlama http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998945/what-is-a-regular-type-in-the-context-of-move-semantics

Comment: You can limit Callable to a copyable type, or it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, I would like to try to push the limit. May be there is hack to do it. I don't really care how dirty it is.

Comment: @Incomputable Why do you need "DefaultConstructible"? An Iterator does not need to be DefaultConstructible, and your Iterator member is almost always never DefaultConstructible.

Comment: @kennytm, you're right, thanks. Removed it.

Comment: if the callable it's not copyable then you have to store a reference (reference type or pointer type) to it, either directly, or via a proxy_container. And you have to watch for dangling references. I don't see a way around it.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. What would you want the copy constructor to do if `Callable` is not copyable? Store references which could dangle, or issue a compiler error?

Comment: @TartanLlama, I believe I will just keep falling back until `std::function` then.

Comment: @Incomputable But `std::function` can't store non-copyable types either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need `std::function`, or the moral equivalent of std::function in what you implement yourself.

Comment: @TartanLlama, you're right. I can implement it by hand then ... It's gonna be (not) fun.

Comment: @Incomputable How do you plan to use your iterator? You could use something like [function views](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html), but only if your iterators will never outlive the `Callable` which they reference.

Comment: @TartanLlama, it actually wraps the underlying iterator. So usage vectors are probably unlimited, even in multithreaded context. `std::shared_ptr<>` would be great in that case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some way to get such a type:

1. Take a reference and store in reference_wrapper.
   Reference is obviously copy constructible.
2. If you want to own the callback and manage the lifetime, store it in shared_ptr.
   This adds many overhead, but it just works.

Comment: I think that `std::function` would be much better fit then.

Comment: std::function erases the type and incur more overhead. If you're doing templates, do not use it.

Comment: I think it should be measured to say for sure. I've heard that type erasure will lose effects when used a lot on the same type.

Comment: a std::shared_ptr based implementation would also need to erase the type and incur similar overhead

Comment: It's unclear that what you're trying to add. std::function still needs the Callable being CopyConstructible, and a reference wrapper is much minimal for adding CopyAssignable.

Comment: @Caleth shared_ptr doesn't necessarily erase the type. Since the concrete type is provided in template argument, the overhead here is reference counting.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi If the callable is destroyed, your reference_wrapper becomes dangling. shared_ptr would be the best.