# is std::vector a non regular type due to its assignment operator moving the location of its members

Tags: c++, vector, regular-type

Vector wraps its array in a way that it pretends that the array's elements are members of the vector itself. This is why you can't modify the array elements of a const vector. The vector also allows you to access the address of its array elements. But, if I get a pointer to an array element of the vector (which is an element of the vector itself), and then I assign to the vector, my pointer is no longer defined to point at an element of the vector. It makes sense for `push_back()`, or something like that, to invalidate pointers because no one said that `push_back()` didn't do something ridiculous to the elements of the vector.

Any regular type would have my pointers to its elements stay valid after assignment. So, not that there aren't workarounds, but wouldn't that make vector a non-regular type?

The same goes for `std::string`, and many other list/storage types in the standard.

edited: meant regular type when I said concrete type.

edit, one more point: so, in c, if you got a pointer to a member of a struct, assigning to that struct literally couldn't change the location of the object, because you couldn't pretend for an array element to be part of a struct. In a vector, however, this rule is broken. A member is a member of the object because it is literally associated with the same object name, and always will be until the object is destroyed. Therefore, no regular operation should be able to change something like this.

Comment: What definition of "concrete type" are you using here? The standard/documentation usually [states when the pointers/iterators become invalid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: "concrete type" is typically used as "not abstract type". In this sense vector is a concrete type. It is not clear what are you trying to ask here. If you need a pointer to an array that won't be managed somewhere else then just use array directly instead of vector.

Comment: a type that behaves almost algebraically and all of its member operators are defined so that they do what makes sense considering their names. For example, when you operator=(something), operator==(something) returns true
(in response to nwp)

Comment: Did you mean [regular type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998945/what-is-a-regular-type-in-the-context-of-move-semantics)?

Comment: "Any concrete type would have my pointers to its elements stay valid after assignment." - where do you get that from?  If that's part of your definition of "concrete type", then obviously vector doesn't fit.  If it isn't part of your definition, where did it come from?

Comment: i believe i did mean regular type. someone told me during a conversation that there was no such thing as a "regular type" and i must've meant concrete type. Sorry for the confusion
(in response to nwp)

Comment: There seems to be no universally accepted definition for regular types in C++. Use your own and check if it applies. Usually pointing to sub-objects is not part of the definition of regular types, so the pointer example should not be relevant.

Comment: i edited my original post with a response

Comment: You're completely confusing concepts.   A concrete class is one that can be instantiated (as distinct from an abstract class, which cannot).   `std::vector` is a templated concrete type.  `std::string` is a concrete type (okay, a specialisation of a templated concrete type).   Invalidating iterators can occur on assignment if resizing (changing size) is involved.  For example, `avec = bvec` invalidates iterators of `avec` if `avec.capacity() < bvec.size()`.   This is a consequence of `std::vector`, `std::string`, and other containers dynamically managing memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of a regular type in C++ comes from Stepanov's Elements of Programming. It's basically a list of reasonable/useful notions on a type. For example, it should support equality, and assignment, and assignment should have the post condition that the assigned-to variable compares equal with the original variable (of course, this is copy assignment and not move assignment).

However, regularity does not include the notion you are describing. Concrete is an entirely different thing, it is basically just any class that can actually be instantiated, i.e. has no pure virtual methods.

Stepanov does have a classification related to what you are describing. I don't have my copy handy, but I think he refers to it as internal vs external: it's a question of whether the bits comprising an instance of the type actually include all the information of that value. A vector is external, because the three pointers that typically comprise the vector itself do not fully describe it, there is also stuff on the heap which is part of the vector's representation even though it's not contained "inside" the actual vector instance.

The issue that you're describing occurs because vector is external. Any time you take pointers that go directly to the external parts of a type, and then perform operations on that type, those pointers may be invalidated. A struct with simple members like int however, is internal, all the information is contained inside the struct itself. This causes the difference in behavior.

If you want a dynamically sized array type, you basically have to use the heap, and using the heap means your type will be external, at which point you open yourself up to these issues. That's why all standard containers have detailed descriptions of when their iterators can be invalidated.